# How to retrieve serial no's from multiple HID(Human Interface Device) by using hidsdi.h?

Tags: c++, hid

there is a method already given in hidsdi.h is HidD_GetSerialNumberString(), but how can I retrieve serial no's of multiple connected HID devices or any other way to retrieve it in CPP?

refer link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidsdi/nf-hidsdi-hidd_getserialnumberstring

expect a method which return array of serial no

Comment: The function is unique to the Microsoft universal C runtime. You must either link against `Hid.lib` or load `Hid.dll` to call the function. The page describes the size of the buffer you provide that the nul-terminated (wide-char) serial number is returned in. A call to the function returns `true` on success, `false` otherwise. Additional reading for the [HidDeviceObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/hid-collections) parameter will describe its use.